Proof, and general definition of converging sequence or Cauchy sequence
While going through this proof (i.e Every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ is bounded) I encountered the following steps which couldn't understand:
$||x_n-x_{N+1}||+||x_{N+1}|| \leq 1+||x_{N+1}||$
since after $n \geq N$ the difference is strictly less than $1$ but why this proof has retained weaker inequality after adding $1$ to $N+1$ 'th term.
Also I have seen definition of Cauchy or converging sequence use $\forall n>N$ in some places and $\forall n \geq N$ in other places. I think it would not affect the definition but why theres no consistency in defintion

$a<b$ implies $a\leq b.$ "Less than or equal to" does not mean they can be equal, only that we are not discounting that possibility.

Basically, this is just the definition of logical 'or'. $a\leq b$ means "$a<b$ or $a=b.$" But if we know a statement $P$ is true, then "$P$ or $Q$" is true for any statement $Q,$ even if we know $Q$ is false.

Could you give an example of sequence where after adding $\epsilon$ to the $N+1$'th term it can be equal to any of $x_{n \geq N}$

Why would we need such an example?

Don't add questions in comments. This question is about Cauchy sequences, not convergent sequences.

ok deleted @ThomasAndrews

was your first comment that strict inequality implies weaker inequality intended for the inequality used inbounded definition ?
